# Where to ask questions on VLC Media Player?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there a site where one can ask questions about settings and usage of a specific media player?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For VLC, [Super User](http://superuser.com) seems like your best bet.

https://superuser.com/tags/vlc-media-player/info

> VLC Media Player is media player/streaming media server by the VideoLAN project. It is a portable, free and open-source, and supports many audio and video compression methods and file formats. It is able to stream media and to transcode multimedia files between formats.
>
> This tag should be used when using VLC command-line options, errors/crashes, enabling/disabling features, updating or issues with any of it's features, including but not limited to:
>
> - Playing Audio/Video
> - Streaming media
> - Transcoding media
> - UPnP Media Server hosting
>
> and more...
>
> Questions should also consider tagging with the appropriate platform or OS tag. VLC is cross-platform, and issues may be specific to a particular platform.
>
> History
>
> VLC was originally the client portion of the the VideoLAN project. The project, started in 1996, was intended to stream multimedia over a university network and consisted of a server and client.
>
> In 1998 the application was completely re-written, the functionality of the server was rolled into the client and the project was renamed VLC.
>
> VLC's development is coordinated by the non-profit organisation, VideoLAN.

Comment: And I guess asking about some other not so popular software on their meta would be the best idea.

Comment: Why? If it's computer software it's more than likely on-topic there. Worst case you might need to create a tag.

Comment: Yes, but whats the harm in asking on their meta before creating a new tag? I am sure that they dont want a new tag for every not-so-popular software.

Comment: @user295376 I wouldn't worry about it. Questions about less popular software that might not be answered elsewhere on the internet are good for us to have.

Comment: @AnnaLear AYE! And I guess this was a reply to the second sentence of my previous comment.

Comment: If you are interested, [this](http://superuser.com/questions/923925/how-to-change-the-default-folder-that-opens-when-i-add-subtitles-in-vlc-mediapla) is the question. Subtitles are a boon while viewing non-english videos :)

Comment: I'm surprised by this answer since Super User's [Help page](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) explicitly forbids questions relating to media players.

Comment: They closed my question: https://superuser.com/q/1675699/397183